# Draw geometric figure containing spherical cap using Tikz latex package

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to generate the following figure using the Tikz latex package ?

[image]

Minimal standalone code will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare the functions you show, and use them in your diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={s=0.6;c=sqrt(1-s*s);},
    thick,scale=3,line cap=round]
 \draw (-1,0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1] -- cycle
  (c,s) -- (0,0) -- (-c,s);
 \draw[gray!60,text=black]  (-c,s) -- (c,s) 
  node[pos=0.75,above]{$\sqrt{1-s^2}$}
   (0,0) -- (0,s) node[pos=0.5,left]{$s$} circle[radius=c];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks alot!